# PHP's dns_get_record returning subdomain record instead of domain record

Tags: php

When I'm using *dns_get_record* for a domain that exists like google.com, everything works fine but if I use it on a domain that doesn't exist, the function gets info from a subdomain on our domain for example test.example.com, how can I prevent that?

```
// Test with working domain
var_dump( dns_get_record('google.com', DNS_A) );
/* works, returns
Array
(
    [host] => google.com
    [class] => IN
    [ttl] => 299
    [type] => A
    [ip] => 172.217.12.142
)
*/

// Test with invalid domain on our website (example.com)
var_dump( dns_get_record('invalidtestingname.com', DNS_A) );
/* Doesn't work, pretend it's a subdomain
Array
(
    [host] => invalidtestingname.com.example.com
    [class] => IN
    [ttl] => 299
    [type] => A
    [ip] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
)
*/
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to run the code in different network :p

Comment: check your php version. it's returning empty array for invalid domain. try here : http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: Yes, I guess maybe our server or PHP has some weird settings.. but I have no idea what's causing this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone has that problem, add a "dot" at the end of the  domain name, for example, instead of

```
dns_get_record('invalidtestingname.com', DNS_A);
```

Do this:

```
dns_get_record('invalidtestingname.com.', DNS_A);
```

Then PHP won't try to check for a subdomain of your own domain and it will search correctly. Not sure how come nobody had that problem before, there aren't even any comments about this on php.net

Comment: Not sure if the issue you are having is an overall PHP issue or something specific to your system configuration.  However, I do know that DNS considers a domain name that **doesn't** end in a dot to be a "relative" sub domain.  So it doesn't surprise me that adding a dot to the end fixed your issue.

Comment: Yeah.. not sure either what is causing this either and I have a feeling it's our configuration, but I'm not familiar with DNS so this trick worked pretty well. I'm surprised nobody ever had that problem, hope it helps other people